# Wont work as i want

Tags: if-statement, lua

Right now they both get executed. What am I doing wrong?

```
if ismsg("talk", msg) then
Say("I do not want to talk about it.")
topic = 1
end

if ismsg("talk", msg) and topic == 1 then
Say("Ok. Get lost!")
idle()
end
```

I only want the second if condition to be triggered if talk is sent a second time.

Comment: The condition that would pass the first if block is creating the needed conditions to trigger the second. Could you need an `else if`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second if statement is always being triggered because you are setting `topic` to 1 in the first if statement.

Try this:

```
if ismsg("talk", msg) and topic == 1 then
    Say("Ok. Get lost!")
    idle()
elseif ismsg("talk", msg) then
    Say("I do not want to talk about it.")
    topic = 1
end
```